# read image upload response

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Im using this code for uploading images:
https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-ImageUpload

When i upload an image i got success notification.
I'm trying to read response from server and also checked task's complete event:

```
task.on("complete", logEvent);

function logEvent(e) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e));        
}
```

and this is the output:

```
{"eventName":"complete","object":{"_observers":{"complete":[{}],"propertyChange":[{}]},"_session":{"_id":"image-upload"},"_id":"image-upload{1}","_description":"{ 'uploading': Test0.png }","_upload":3807297,"_totalUpload":3807297,"_status":"complete"},"response":{}}
```

as you can see response is null. So how can i read the response from server?

Comment: Is it multipart upload?

Comment: @Dlucidone yes it is.

Comment: Is it for iOS multipart upload?

Comment: @Dlucidone No, it's for android

Comment: This is happening for me in case of iOS and sent a pull request for that.the issue you are facing is with the file name being sent to upload or the path issue.

Answer (score -1):

the data told you why is null ?
it is not finish to upload is only in session. 
look [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-ImageUpload/blob/master/app/main-page.js) at the send image function , what are youy need to do.